# Saving model in Tensorflow not working under GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

**UPDATE: I've found out that the below code DOES work correctly when using tensorflow-cpu. The problem only persists when using tensorflow-gpu. How can I make it work?**

I cannot find the problem in my code - I am trying to save my variables, and then reload them, and they don't appear to load from the saved model.

I will note that they DO load if I do the saving and loading in the same python run (without the process ending and running the testing script). My problem is that this doesn't work when I train the mode -> save it -> process ends -> run script again with testing flag -> model is loaded without error, but the results are as if it wasn't.

Code:

Run #1

```
# creating LSTM model...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # training...

    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./saved_models/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Run #2

```
# creating the same exact LSTM model...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    saver.restore(sess, "./saved_models/model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")

    # testing...
```

If I run these two snippets back to back, I get the desired output - the model is trained to predict a trivial sequence, and it predicts it properly during testing. If I run the two snippets separately, the model predicts the wrong sequence during testing.

Update: I was suggested to try importing the MetaGraph and it's not working either. Code:

Run #1

```
# creating model...

tf.add_to_collection('a', net.a)
# adding nodes ...
tf.add_to_collection('z', net.z)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # training...
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./saved_models/my-model")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Run #2

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./saved_models/my-model.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, './saved_models/my-model')

    net.a = tf.get_collection('a')[0]
    # adding nodes ...
    net.z = tf.get_collection('z')[0]

    # testing...
```

The above code runs correctly - but the testset result shows it is not post-training (and again, if I run the two snippets in the same Python instance, it works correctly).

This should be fairly trivial and I just cannot get it to work. Any help is welcome. Specifically, I don't really need to save the entire graph either - just the variables (some of them inside the LSTM cell).

Comment: Try importing the meta graph (tf.train.import_meta_graph). https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph

Comment: This did not work for me either. Added the relevant code to the question...

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem, and I guess you use `tf.Variable()`, right?
Try to change it to `tf.get_variable()`. It worked for me :)

Comment: I am using get_variable